# Create Table on Plugin Activation

Tags: plugins

```
// Initialization and Hooks
global $wpdb;
global $wp_version;
global $wpmyfirstplugin_version;
global $wpmyfirstplugin_db_version;
global $wpmyfirstplugin_table_name;
global $wp_version;
$wpmyfirstplugin_version = '1.0.1';
$wpmyfirstplugin_db_version = '0.0.1';
$wpmyfirstplugin_table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'imart_setting';

function wpmyfirstplugin_install()
{
    global $wpdb;
    global $wpmyfirstplugin_table_name;
    global $wpmyfirstplugin_db_version;

    // create table on first install
    if($wpdb->get_var("show tables like '$wpmyfirstplugin_table_name'") != $wpmyfirstplugin_table_name) {
        wpmyfirstplugin_createTable($wpdb, $wpmyfirstplugin_table_name);

    //add_option("wpmyfirstplugin_db_version", $wpmyfirstplugin_db_version);
        //add_option("wpmyfirstplugin_configuration", '');
    }

}

function wpmyfirstplugin_createTable($wpdb, $table_name)
{
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE  ".$table_name." (
          main_id bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
          main_key varchar(255) default NULL,
          main_value longtext,
          PRIMARY KEY  (`imart_id`)
        ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;";

    $results = $wpdb->query($sql);
}


register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'wpmyfirstplugin_createTable');
```

Above is what I key in for starter. When I activate I get the following:

> Warning: Missing argument 2 for wpmyfirstplugin_createTable()

This one point to the execution of `wpmyfirstplugin_createTable` at

```
wpmyfirstplugin_createTable($wpdb, $wpmyfirstplugin_table_name);
```

> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object

This one point to the line where I run

```
$results = $wpdb->query($sql);
```

What did I do wrong actually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because 'wpmyfirstplugin_createTable' is called on register_activation_hook. This hook is called when a plugin is activated from dashboard and before declaring any variable. So when this function runs it does not get the table name parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the:

```
maybe_create_table( string $table_name, string $create_ddl );
// be sure to include this before calling the function. 
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/maybe_create_table/

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
function test_db_install() 
{
    global $wpdb;
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
   $sql="
       CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `".$wpdb->prefix."imart_setting`
     (
          main_id bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
          main_key varchar(255) default NULL,
          main_value longtext,
          PRIMARY KEY  (`main_id`)
     );";
    dbDelta($sql);

$insert_sql ="
    INSERT INTO `wp_posts`(`post_author`, `post_date`, `post_date_gmt`, `post_content`, `post_title`, `post_excerpt`, `post_status`, `comment_status`, `ping_status`, `post_password`, `post_name`, `to_ping`, `pinged`, `post_modified`, `post_modified_gmt`, `post_content_filtered`, `post_parent`, `guid`, `menu_order`, `post_type`, `post_mime_type`, `comment_count`) VALUES ('admin','','','[Alumini Dashboard]','Dashbord','','publish','','','','dashbord','','','','','','','','','page','','')";

        dbDelta($insert_sql);
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to how your code works and how it should be used

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this

```
// Initialization and Hooks
global $wpdb;
global $wp_version;
global $wpmyfirstplugin_version;
global $wpmyfirstplugin_db_version;
global $wpmyfirstplugin_table_name;
global $wp_version;
$wpmyfirstplugin_version = '1.0.1';
$wpmyfirstplugin_db_version = '0.0.1';
$wpmyfirstplugin_table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'imart_setting';
function wpmyfirstplugin_install(){
global $wpdb;
global $wpmyfirstplugin_table_name;
global $wpmyfirstplugin_db_version;
// create table on first install
if($wpdb->get_var("show tables like '$wpmyfirstplugin_table_name'") != $wpmyfirstplugin_table_name) {
    wpmyfirstplugin_createTable($wpmyfirstplugin_table_name);

}
}
function wpmyfirstplugin_createTable($table_name){
global $wpdb;
$sql = "CREATE TABLE  ".$table_name." (
      main_id bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
      main_key varchar(255) default NULL,
      main_value longtext,
      PRIMARY KEY  (`imart_id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;";

$results = $wpdb->query($sql);
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'wpmyfirstplugin_install');
```